# Is there a way to lower the viewport resolution using eevee?

Tags: 3d-view, resolution

I'm using blender 3.0 and I have a 5k monitor. I'd like to reduce the resolution viewport to get better performance in eevee, not cycles. Is this possible? I don't want to make the viewport smaller, I just don't need the viewport to be rendering in 4k+.

Comment: Untested (I'm in same boat, use a lower res additional monitor for fast rendered preview), but I'd recommend using a smaller viewport and looking into screen magnification software.

Comment: It could be a thing, to suggest the devs to implement [Cycles' Pixel Size](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/performance.html#viewport) into Eevee.